# Error occurs when i use jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax

$('#deviceLoadMore') is a link. When this link is being clicked, it will trigger a ajax to the web service I have created.

The problem I'm having now is it keeps on throwing this error in the console.log
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON. But when I just paste the ajax part in the console.log, it able to retrieve the data back. I have checked that all the value is just a normal string and integer.

I was wondering why i can trigger in console log without having any issue and couldn't if i just click on the link?

```
var currentContextSection = '<%=currentSection %>';
    var currentTemplateIds = '<%=templateIds %>';
    var currentItemPerPage = <%=itemPerPage %>;
    var currentPageIndex = <%=currentPage %>;

    var arguments = { templateIds:'<%=templateIds %>' ,  currentSection:'<%=templateIds %>',  currentPage:currentPageIndex,  itemPerPage:currentItemPerPage };
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#deviceLoadMore').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/AJAX/WS.asmx/GetItems",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(arguments),
                dataProcess: false
            }).done(function (data) {
                test = data;
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            });
        });
    });
```

------ EDIT  -------
If I have this:

```
var arguments = {"templateIds":currentTemplateIds ,"currentSection":currentContextSection,"currentPage":currentPageIndex,"itemPerPage":currentItemPerPage};
```

and executing with the ajax data:JSON.stringify(arguments), i will get the following errror:
Converting circular structure to JSON.
When I console.log the "arguments", it displays:

```
Object {templateIds: "963C1D18A93849309D6014CE2135173C", currentSection: "Personal", currentPage: 1, itemPerPage: 8}
```

And it displays this when I console.log JSON.stringify(arguments):

```
"{"templateIds":"963C1D18A93849309D6014CE2135173C","currentSection":"Personal","currentPage":1,"itemPerPage":8}"
```

After google around for some successfully implemented ajax sample, I changed my code to the following, and it works! And I have no idea why it works this way.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#deviceLoadMore').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/AJAX/WS.asmx/GetItems",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({"templateIds":currentTemplateIds ,"currentSection":currentContextSection,"currentPage":currentPageIndex,"itemPerPage":currentItemPerPage}),
            dataProcess: false
        }).done(function (data) {
            test = data;
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to put initialization of arguments inside document.ready?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` this error is fired when you try to use like a property of an object the same object or a reference of this. like `obj = {}, obj.a = a` or `a = {}; b = a, a.a = b`, in this two cases you can't use JSON.stringify() because a.a is a reference of itself.

Comment: What append in console if you do console.log(arguments) just after the arguments initialisation

Answer (score 0):

try after removing, **JSON.stringify** from

```
 data: JSON.stringify(arguments),
```